# Map of Maps Initialization in Application Context

Tags: spring

I want to initialize a Map of Maps in the Spring context file. I'm getting this xsd error.

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'map'. No child element is expected at this point.

This is the bean defnition:

```
<bean id="voToDOMapper" class="com.yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.configuration.VOToDOMapper" factory-method="getInstance">
    <property name="channelToMapper">
    <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.util.HashMap">
        <entry key="yyy" >
        <value>
            <map>
                <entry key="com.yyy.yyy.yyy.AsyncAddressChangeEventVO">
                    <value>com.yyy.yyy.yyy.vo.yyy.FakeAcctAddressEvent</value>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </value>
        </entry>
    </map>
    </property>

</bean>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way

```
<util:map>
        <entry key="x" value-ref="val1"></entry>
</util:map>

<util:map id="val1">
    <entry key="a" value="blob"></entry>
    <entry key="b" value="clob"></entry>
</util:map>
```

enable xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util

Comment: can you give me the complete bean definition?

Comment: This got me well on my way!  thanks. @VanchinathanChandrasekaran -   You don't necessarily NEED a bean definition beyond the above, but if you want to define the wrapping map (i.e. the first map above) you could explicitly set a MapFactoryBean with a java.util.HashMap property for its targetMapClass...again not sure it's really necessary

Answer (score 1):

Example of using of util: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/CreateListMapInContext.htm